# MagnificPopup won´t work with Typo3

Tags: typo3, magnific-popup

I would like to use [magnific popup](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/jh_magnificpopup) for a site which is still in development, but unfortunately nothing happens after the installation and adding the static content in my template.

No matter what i try no popup comes up.

If someone would like to help me i will provide access to the site.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

First thing to do:
look at your source code: does the 'link' show any sign of 'magnific popup' code?
Added classes? id?

Second: do you see any extra javascript and/or stylesheet that is added by the extension?

If you answer negative to 1 of these, the extension does not output anything. Sounds logic, but it is the first step. Is it a solution? Nope, it means your live just got a bit more worse, but hang in there !

If it does show any code from the ext: look at your console, are there any js errors occurred ? (if you don't know what console is, or (even worse) you work with IE) please read about chrome console of at least install Firefox with firebug.
My best beth would be a JS error...

Can it be possible that the ext itself does not work?
Does your php error logs tell you that the extension is behaving badly?
Do you see errors in the typoscript analyser (or whatever it's called to analyse the css_styled_content and other TS spaghetti  )
If not, then no, it is not the ext.

Again, i'm betting my wive, three horses and a barrel of beer on JS erros.

Good luck mate !

ps: IF i'm wrong, i'm not sending you my wife by postal service. Loads of trouble last time. Nor the horses, same shizzle ..